# Problems with cordova-plugin-ms-adal and iOS13

Tags: cordova, ios13, adal, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

We are having problems with AD Azure authentication using cordova-plugin-ms-adal on iOS13. This is from a cordova application, packaged and installed on through the app store. It works fine on iOS12 and Android but on iOS13 it silently fails resulting in a 'blank page' as none of the callbacks are triggered.

Below is sample code, from the plug-in documentation page for illustration. The 'acquireTokenSilentAsync' and 'acquireTokenAsync' (if called directly) both fail but do not trigger any error callbacks.

I know the ADAL cordova plugin is no longer supported by Microsoft (since March 2019) but I am trying to establish whether the plugin can somehow be used with iOS13 or if we would have to switch to some other mechanism (e.g. MSAL)?

In short, does anyone know with certainty whether the cordova-plugin-ms-adal plugin can be made to work with iOS13, for a packaged cordova app, and if not, what would be a good substitute?

```
// Shows user authentication dialog if required
function authenticate(authCompletedCallback, errorCallback) {
  var authContext = new Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext(authority);
  authContext.tokenCache.readItems().then(function (items) {
    if (items.length > 0) {
        authority = items[0].authority;
        authContext = new Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext(authority);
    }
    // Attempt to authorize user silently
    authContext.acquireTokenSilentAsync(resourceUri, clientId)
    .then(authCompletedCallback, function () {
        // We require user credentials so triggers authentication dialog
        authContext.acquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientId, redirectUri)
        .then(authCompletedCallback, errorCallback);
    });
  });
};

authenticate(function(authResponse) {
  console.log("Token acquired: " + authResponse.accessToken);
  console.log("Token will expire on: " + authResponse.expiresOn);
}, function(err) {
  console.log("Failed to authenticate: " + err);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the [azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova) is in an archived state and is no longer supported, it's better to move your application to the [microsoft-authentication-library-for-js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js). Also, you can find the AngularJS/Angular wrapped version of this plugin in the repository. This implementation has similar methods to the Cordova version. The only difference is that you don't need to add it as a Cordova plugin, but instead as a JavaScript dependency.

Comment: Wait, but then you don't have access to the shared adal cache of the OS...?

Answer (score 0):

Use it in a device ready function, it will work fine.

Example:-

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
  Call your authentication code
}
```